# MySQL: splitting result into two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a result as follows

```
DATE        EID TIME        TYPE

2015-07-26  1   10:01:00    IN 
2015-07-26  1   15:01:00    OUT 
2015-07-26  1   18:33:00    IN 
2015-07-26  1   23:11:00    OUT
```

I want to split IN, OUT into different columns `ORDER BY date, eid, time`. expected result should be as follows

```
DATE        EID     IN TIME     OUT TIME

2015-07-26  1       10:01:00    15:01:00
2015-07-26  1       18:33:00    23:11:00
```

This is what I tried so far

```
SELECT `date` AS 'DATE', `eid` AS 'EID',
CASE WHEN `type` = 'IN' THEN `time` END AS 'IN TIME',
CASE WHEN `type` = 'OUT' THEN `time` END AS 'OUT TIME'
FROM `attendance`
ORDER BY `date`, `eid`, `time`;
```

It's fetching some ridiculous result as follows

```
DATE        EID     IN TIME     OUT TIME

2015-07-26  1       10:01:00    null
2015-07-26  1       null        15:01:00
2015-07-26  1       18:33:00    null
2015-07-26  1       null        23:11:00
```

### UPDATED:

This is my table structure

```
Field       Type                Null    Key     Default     Extra

id      int(10) unsigned        NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
eid     int(10) unsigned        NO              NULL
time    time                    NO              00:00:00
date    date                    NO              0000-00-00
type    enum('IN', 'OUT')       NO              NULL
state   tinyint(1) unsigned     NO              1
```

Here is more tuples...

```
DATE        EID TIME        TYPE

2015-07-26  1   10:01:00    IN
2015-07-26  1   15:01:00    OUT
2015-07-26  1   18:33:00    IN
2015-07-26  1   23:11:00    OUT
2015-07-26  3   09:42:00    IN
2015-07-26  3   15:29:00    OUT
2015-07-26  3   18:20:00    IN
2015-07-26  3   00:34:00    OUT
2015-07-26  6   14:16:00    IN
2015-07-26  6   23:08:00    OUT
2015-07-26  8   13:32:00    IN
2015-07-26  8   23:57:00    OUT
2015-07-26  12  09:14:00    IN
2015-07-26  12  15:07:00    OUT
2015-07-26  12  17:28:00    IN
2015-07-26  12  23:53:00    OUT
2015-07-26  13  13:47:00    IN
2015-07-26  13  23:25:00    OUT
2015-07-26  15  11:07:00    IN
2015-07-26  15  19:50:00    OUT
```

Comment: Your data set is too small and too convenient. What if you have two (or more) records with the same `type` one right after another?

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier for each of these records?

Comment: We must know if you have some identifiers that describes two rows for example in and out, unique for each set. Maybe after the in is always out for the sasme date and eid? Tell us more.

Comment: could you please explain bit more about your table structure EID...

Comment: @PM77-1 yes it is, date could be various range such as 2015-07-26 to 2015-08-26. eid means enroll ID. for each employee there is an eid. it is unique for each employee. but date, eid and type is repeating in attendance table.

Comment: @SunnyS.M table structure is updated above...

Comment: @PatrykImosa for each date there is at least one IN OUT rows per eid. it could be more than one IN OUT rows per eid. I'll update more data so you can understand the schema.

Comment: But there can not be IN, IN ? There always is IN, OUT. I mean about the date for eid

Comment: @PatrykImosa nope, I handled those exceptions. for attendance table there will be only IN, OUT rows per EID. I think you can understand it by my updated data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a query for you. I am hoping it will solve your problem :

**SQL FOR TABLE SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `eid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**SQL Query FOR RESULT**

I have assumed that there is an auto increment column available in your table as `id`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.`date` AS 'DATE', a.`eid` AS 'EID',
        CASE WHEN `type` = 'IN' THEN a.`time` END AS 'IN TIME',
        CASE WHEN `type` = 'IN' THEN 
            (select `time` from `attendance` where id > a.id AND `type` = 'OUT' LIMIT 1) END AS 'OUT TIME'
        FROM `attendance` a
        ORDER BY a.`date`, a.`eid`, a.`time`
) as t WHERE t.`IN TIME` IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: your query is fix my expetion. thank you Satender. It work like a charm. here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da4a5d/2) for it.

Comment: @Hiran, What if the order records entrance is not same as the Date of the records? See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0413/1

Comment: We have added order by clause in query you can check that Taher

Comment: It does not solve it, see the fiddle, You search in the bigger Ids which is not correct, if the order is not same as the date and time

Comment: @TaherRahgooy you are correct, if records are not in order it'll be buggy. but here is the case. this attendance table is generating from automated algorithmic process which programmed in java. I've solve it and it'll never be unordered. this data set is always same as ordered above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data are valid (there is not more than one `IN` between two `OUT`), using window functions:

```
SELECT DATE, EID, `IN`, `OUT` FROM 
  (SELECT date AS 'DATE', eid AS 'EID', 
     (SELECT MAX(TIME) from attendance  where
            DATE = a.DATE AND TIME <= a.TIME AND TYPE = 'IN' AND EID = a.EID) as 'IN',
     (SELECT MAX(TIME) from attendance  where
            DATE = a.DATE AND TIME <= a.TIME AND TYPE = 'OUT' AND EID = a.EID) as 'OUT',
      TYPE           
   FROM attendance a
   WHERE TYPE = 'OUT'
   ORDER BY date, eid, time) t
```

here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23548/41) for it.

Edit: I did not check the `EID`, here is the new [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da4a5d/4).

Comment: this query has some exceptions in result. here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da4a5d/1) for your query with some data. check the output result and compare it with my expectation result which mentioned in the question.

Comment: The query was finding max of the time for all `EID`, I corrected the answer

Comment: Taher look at the column `EID` row `3`, it has some exceptions.

Comment: It is correct, because , before `OUT` time `'00:34:00'` there is no `IN`. The `IN` you entered is `'18:20:00'` which is after it. Right?

Comment: the problem is 'IN' Column has many repeated rows. as an example 'IN TIME 14:16:00' is repeated over the 'EID 1, 3, 12' and 'IN TIME 18:33:00' is repeated over the 'EID 1, 6, 8, 12, 13, 15'. checkout yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have added another answer for it just to fix the issue what Taher is saying :

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT a.`date` AS 'DATE', a.`eid` AS 'EID',
    CASE WHEN `type` = 'IN' THEN a.`time` END AS 'IN TIME',
    CASE WHEN `type` = 'IN' THEN 
        (select `time` from
            (SELECT `date`, `eid`, `time`,`type`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as id FROM `attendance` cross join (select @rownum := 0) r ORDER BY `date`, `eid`, `time`) as b where (b.id > a.id) AND `type` = 'OUT' LIMIT 1)
         END AS 'OUT TIME'

    FROM(SELECT `date`, `eid`, `time`,`type`, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as id FROM `attendance` cross join (select @rownum := 0) r ORDER BY `date`, `eid`, `time`) as a
) as t WHERE t.`IN TIME` IS NOT NULL;
```